# Hyperthreading with pipeline and superscalar architecture together?

Tags: multithreading, optimization

Can a system use hyper threading , pipelining and superscalar simultaneously to speed up program execution?
As hyper threading can be thought of as two pipelines and is an optimisation of superscalar does that mean a system can you use all three together? 
If not what three techniques could be used together to speed up a programs execution?

Comment: afaik, arm doesn't have hyper-threading.

Comment: On what processor do you want to execute your application? Do you use any libraries for parallel execution, e.g. OpenMP?

Answer (score 0):

Three techniques that can be used together to speed up program execution are:

1. Deeper pipelines with more pipelines stages.
2. Parallel pipelines with several ALUs working at once (superscalar).
3. Refactoring the program to run faster (software only).

AFAIK, nothing stops hyperthreading, pipelining and superscalar to speed up program simultaneously.